# same navbar with unique heading loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a website which will carry out the same navbar on each webpage. I Have managed to create the same navbar all over using simple jquery techniques. My navbar has a sidebar element with bootstrap styling incorporated. to the right of the sidebar, I have to generate unique heading which corresponds to the webpage click on the navbar. I would like to know is it a way out to create different headings using javascript or jquery.

nav.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 sidebar1">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/group_logo.jpg" class="img-responsive align-middle" alt="Logo">
        <hr align="left" width="200px;">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="left-navigation">
        <ul class="list">
          <!--<h5><strong>Actionlist</strong></h5>-->
          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></i><a href="grading.html">Seating</a></li>
          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i><a href="report.html">Report</a></li>                         
        </ul>                         
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 main-content">
      <!--Main content code to be written here --> 

      <h1>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
        Dashboard
      </h1>
      <hr align="left" width="100%">

      <!-- Create action buttons -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `index.html` I have the below code under body tag to load the container. How can I create the unique heading for different HTML pages?

```
 <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>

 <script>
   $.get("nav.html", function(data) {
     $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: What is your server side program which serves the pages?

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Are the headings for these pages the name of the navigation links, e.g: Dashboard, Seating, etc? Otherwise, where are you supposed to reference the heading for each page (the name has got to come from somewhere)? And where should it be inserted into the DOM structure?

Comment: currently I am not using any server side programming. @UncaughtTypeError yes heading is supposed to be Dashboard , Settings and so on. It needs to be placed to the right top corner of each page next to  side navbar.

Comment: What does your DOM/html structure look like at "the right top corner of each page next to side navbar"? I need to reference an element to target in order to insert the page title.

Comment: its been added in my code under main content code <h1>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
        Dashboard
      </h1>
      <hr align="left" width="100%">

Comment: A solution has been given - just a friendly reminder; remember to use the `@` symbol as a mention so that I get notified on direct responses to questions I've asked in the comments - would've missed your response if I didn't check back out of curiosity.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thank you for the solution. I will implement it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filename to set the header once the page is loaded.

```
             <h1>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
              <span id="nav-placeholder">Dashboard</span>
            </h1>
```

And then use the script like this -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var navPlaceholder= "";
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    switch(filename) {
        case "seaing.html":
            navPlaceholder = "Seating";
        break;

        case "report.html":
            navPlaceholder = "Report";
        break;

        default:
            navPlaceholder = "Dashboard";
        break;   
    }

    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(navPlaceholder);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should give you the idea and steer you in the right direction.

1. Store the link in a variable;
2. Store the title of the link in a variable;

**Demonstration:**

```
<script>
$('.left-navigation a').on('click', function(){
  var getUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
      getTitle = $(this).text();

      /* Log variable to console - remove for production */
      console.log('The Url:',getUrl);
      console.log('The Title:',getTitle);

  $.get(getUrl, function(data) {
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    $('#page-title').text(getTitle); /* Update the page title */
  });
});
</script>
```

To target the right element in order to update the page title, update your html structure as follows:

```
<h1><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i> <span id="page-title">Dashboard</span></h1>
```

We don't want the script to remove the glyphicon icon nested within your `h1` element, so we wrap the text that needs to update in an element we can target specifically (`#page-title`).